# enable binlog in MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, log-files

How can I enable binlog in mysql? The documents say to start the server with `--log-bin` but when I do:

```
service mysql start --log-bin=/binlog
```

I get:

```
start: invalid option: --log-bin=/binlog
```

And when I add

```
log-bin = /binlog
```

to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` it doesn't log anything.

Comment: Uncomment the log_bin line from your my.cnf

Comment: @dan - what's that supposed to do? It's already not working without it.

Comment: Please share my.cnf and the log since you restart the mysqld

Comment: @Anatoly - it's too long to share. It's just the default file with the extra line I added at the end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"service mysql start" won't accept mysql-specific options, since that's a command of the init system. You would need to pass the `--log-bin` to mysqld. But you should prefer specifying that in the config file ;-)

add in the [mysqld] stanza of my.cnf

```
log-bin = /path/to/log
```

and maybe:

```
expire-logs-days = 14
max-binlog-size  = 500M
server-id        = 1
```

and beware that the specified file+path must be writable by the mysql user! Your example specified /binlog. The mysql user ist surely not allowed to write files in /. You may specify a relative path like `log-bin=binlog` which will then create a file called binlog inside your MySQL data directory where permissions are already set up.

Comment: I think you're on to something, I didn't realize the line had to go in a specific section, I moved it to the mysqld area and now I get: `start: Job failed to start` - /binlog is 777 and owned my mysql.mysql - this is in a vagrant VM by the way. Any ideas?

Comment: This may be due to AppArmor blocking MySQL, as */binlog* is a non-standard location. Check your logs.

Comment: If you skip an argument to *log-bin*, it will be saved in your data directory as *${HOSTNAME}-bin*.

Comment: Thanks @sam_pan_mariusz - skipping the argument does work, probably AppArmor is the culprit I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 for mysql 5.7 `my.cnf` includes config files under `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`. To enable bin log these options should be add to file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Thanks @matt_gnu and @cubbuk. This is also true for Ubuntu 20.10 - `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Comment: Forgot to mention: MySQL 8.0.23

Comment: Everywhere `-` is used, replace that with `_`. Atleast that was the case with me (Mysql 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL 5.7 you will also need to add the `server-id` as follows

```
[mysqld]
 server_id=master-01
 log_bin
```

If you do not add the `server_id` option, the server will not start. This is from the [MySQL 5.7 reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin).

Comment: where are the logs saved when you don't specify the path?

Comment: @YahyaUddin which logs? Do you mean the binary logs? The binary logs are stored in datadir folder

Comment: Where's that? .....

Comment: I was banging my head from an hour... Thanks for the tip on `server-id`.

Answer (score 3):

service mysqld stop

Edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf : Under the logging and Replication 
Locate log_bin. Un comment the log_bin

service mysqld start

Answer (score -4):

You can start the server with

```
mysqld --log-bin=/binlog
```

Comment: That's a one-time approach at best, not suitable for production use.

Comment: Agree, His question was it says "invalid option" when he use --login-bin option. This is how you use the option.